# How to assign null value to column in view so that it has datatype of type DATE?

Tags: sql, oracle, view

I created a view by assigning null to some columns:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE EDITIONABLE VIEW "EMPLOYEE" (
    "EMPLOYEEID",
    "GLOBALEMPLOYEEID",
    "MANAGERUSERID",
    "SOURCE",
    "STARTDATECOMPANY",
    "USERID"
) AS
    SELECT
        C.EMPLOYEEID,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        C.USERID,
        NULL
    FROM
        EMPLOYEE_DATA C
```

All these null columns are defined as `varchar2` in view. But there is a column called `STARTDATECOMPANY` which should be defined as `date` not `varchar2`.

[image]

Is there any way to change datatype of that column to `date` in the view definition and keep null value assigned?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `CAST (NULL as DATE)` as follows:

```
SQL> CREATE VIEW TVIEW AS
  2      SELECT
  3          CAST(NULL AS DATE) DT
  4      FROM
  5          DUAL;

View created.

SQL> DESC TVIEW;
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 DT                                                 DATE

SQL>
```

Cheers!!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `to_date()` function instead, with a format model matching the way you're constructing the first argument.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE EDITIONABLE VIEW "EMPLOYEE" 
("EMPLOYEEID", "GLOBALEMPLOYEEID", "MANAGERUSERID", "SOURCE", "STARTDATECOMPANY", "USERID") AS 
SELECT c.EMPLOYEEID, null, null, null, To_Date(NULL, 'YYYYMMDD'), c.USERID, null
FROM EMPLOYEE_DATA c
```

Comment: `To_Date(NULL, 'YYYYMMDD')` ?? I think even the format string is not needed here. You can simply write `To_Date(NULL)` as it is anyway `NULL`